# Optaplanner 7.9.0 and Adding Multithreading: same planningId exception

Tags: optaplanner

I've had an optaplanner project working for a while now that is allocating jobs to a list of workers using various scoring properties all written in java.  Happy with the way it was working I decided to update from 7.7.0 to 7.9.0 and turn on the new multithreading option and see if it works any faster.  However, I now get the following error:

**Exception in thread "Thread-8" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The move thread with moveThreadIndex (0) has thrown an exception. Relayed here in the parent thread.
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The externalObject (...Worker@72d2327a) cannot be looked up.
Maybe give the class (class Worker) a PlanningId annotation or change the PlanningSolution annotation's LookUpStrategyType or don't rely on functionality that depends on ScoreDirector.lookUpWorkingObject().**

So I tried adding @PlanningId to the unique identifier of the worker class and I get:

**Exception in thread "Thread-7" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The workingObjects (Worker@4438b624, Worker@4438b624) have the same planningId ((class Worker,50)). Working objects must be unique.**

...but it looks like it's comparing a Worker object with itself, so of course it's the same id????

Perhaps this is down to my java code in the assign/unassign methods but I don't understand where this issue is coming from, anyone have any ideas?

**Edit:**
So after a lot of help from @n1ck I got as far as changing the method in the @PlanningSolution class that returns the list of Workers to create new instances each time but with the same values.  This the changes the error to be : **'...The workingObjects (Worker@1eba2b4d, Worker@67a7ef08) have the same planningId...'** So it's no longer comparing identical instances but does seem to be comparing it to an instance from a previous call.  This does however at least confirm there is no duplication per List returned.  So I then changed the planning id to be a new (Long) field whose value is always incremented from the last instance created i.e. first call Worker ids are 1-10, next call 11-20 and so on.  This bypasses the error altogether but now nothing gets allocated to the Workers.  It does the initial set up and null assigns and then stops until the time limit on the solver is reached.  I still think this is something I haven't set right but the error is possibly a bit of a red herring, however as requested the full stack trace as I can see it is:

**Exception in thread "Thread-10" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The workingObjects (Worker@42094cc1, Worker@647a1c5c) have the same planningId ((class Worker,50)). Working objects must be unique.
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.lookup.PlanningIdLookUpStrategy.addWorkingObject(PlanningIdLookUpStrategy.java:40)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.lookup.LookUpManager.addWorkingObject(LookUpManager.java:49)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.lookup.LookUpManager.resetWorkingObjects(LookUpManager.java:43)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.AbstractScoreDirector.setWorkingSolution(AbstractScoreDirector.java:167)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.incremental.IncrementalScoreDirector.setWorkingSolution(IncrementalScoreDirector.java:62)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.scope.DefaultSolverScope.setWorkingSolutionFromBestSolution(DefaultSolverScope.java:230)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolver.solvingStarted(AbstractSolver.java:75)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solvingStarted(DefaultSolver.java:210)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:190)
    at SolverThread.run(SolverThread.java:86)**

**Edit**: @PlanningSolution class as requested:

```
package code.test.scheduler;

import org.optaplanner.core.api.domain.solution.PlanningEntityCollectionProperty;
import org.optaplanner.core.api.domain.solution.PlanningScore;
import org.optaplanner.core.api.domain.solution.PlanningSolution;
import org.optaplanner.core.api.domain.solution.drools.ProblemFactCollectionProperty;
import org.optaplanner.core.api.domain.valuerange.ValueRangeProvider;
import org.optaplanner.core.api.score.buildin.hardmediumsoft.HardMediumSoftScore;
import org.optaplanner.persistence.xstream.api.score.buildin.hardmediumsoft.HardMediumSoftScoreXStreamConverter;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamConverter;

@PlanningSolution
public class Planner
{       
@ProblemFactCollectionProperty
private java.util.List<Worker> _workerList;
@ValueRangeProvider(id="workerRange")
@ProblemFactCollectionProperty
public java.util.List<Worker> getWorkerList() {
    return _workerList;
}
public void setWorkerList(java.util.List<Worker> newWorkerList) {
    _workerList = newWorkerList;
}
public int getWorkerListSize() {
    return _workerList.size();
}

@ProblemFactCollectionProperty
private int[][] _travelTimes;
@ValueRangeProvider(id="travelTimes")
@ProblemFactCollectionProperty
public int[][] getTravelTimes() {
    return _travelTimes;
}
public void setTravelTimes(int[][] newTravelTimes) {
    _travelTimes = newTravelTimes;
}

@PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
private java.util.List<Job> _jobList;
public java.util.List<Job> getJobList() {
    return _jobList;        
}
public void setJobList(java.util.List<Job> newJobList) {
    _jobList = newJobList;
}

@XStreamConverter(HardMediumSoftScoreXStreamConverter.class)
private HardMediumSoftScore _score;

@PlanningScore
public HardMediumSoftScore getScore() {
    return _score;
}

public void setScore(HardMediumSoftScore score) {
    _score = score;     
}
}
```

Comment: The first exception is normal, it's a req for multithreaded solving. I 'll check if the docs clearly state that. The second one is more interesting: `workingObjects (Worker@4438b624, Worker@4438b624)` yes, that's twice the same instance (presuming you didn't overwrite `ObjecttoString()`). What's the full stack trace of that second exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have some duplicate entities in your PlanningEntityCollection. Are you sure all Worker objects in this list are unique (as in, not the same instance)?

I duplicated an entity in my entity collection on purpose, and got the same error.

**Edit**: it turned out the issue was declaring the `@ProblemFactCollectionProperty` annotation above both the field and getter. It should only be declared above one or the other. Declaring it above both the field and getter, in conjunction with using the `@PlanningId` annotation, will result in the 'Working objects must be unique' error.

Comment: I believe not, but on the off chance I'm being thick, how did you create this deliberately? Perhaps that will lead me to my error.  I did try double checking with a small problem data set and couldn't see any duplication but perhaps there is a way you know of to create this issue mid-solve?  It was working with the older optaplanner, but I make a point never to underestimate my own incompetance.

Comment: I simply took the first entity of my entity collection and added it again. So i didn't create the issue mid-solve. The only way I can think of to reproduce it mid-solve is through a problem fact change. I assume you get this error right away and not after some time, right?
The reason everything was working with the older version of Optaplanner is probably because you didn't use the @PlanningId annotation before, maybe you could try to use it with 7.7.

Comment: I'll try 7.7 with the annotation as you are correct, but I'm only using the annotation at all because the first exception suggests it.  Is there an alternate solution to that error?

Comment: Looking at the source code of Optaplanner, maybe setting the LookUpStrategy through the @PlanningSolution annotation would work. You can change it to EQUALITY, but this would require you to implement equals and hashcode in entities and variables.
Example: `@PlanningSolution(lookUpStrategyType = LookUpStrategyType.EQUALITY)`. However, there is no reason @PlanningId shouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks for that. It's something else to try.  I got a bit diverted into looking further at the stack trace of the error.  It's occuring after resetWorkingObjects but I'm wondering if since the Worker(s) are planning facts and therefore not reset (or don't need to be) it's just adding them again itself? I also checked the solution when run without the annotation and there are no duplications after the solution is determined either.

Comment: It looks like the code you are referring to is adding the working objects to a new, empty HashMap. I can give you one last suggestion without looking at your code. I found this in the documentation, however I don't know if this is the case for you: _There can be **multiple @ProblemFactCollectionProperty annotated members**. Those can even return a Collection with the same class type, **but they shouldn’t return the same instance twice**. Instead of Collection, it can also return an array._

Comment: That's the bit I hadn't done right.  Though this makes no difference ordinarily it caused the error.  So it literally WAS comparing something to itself. However now I've got it duplicating the Workers in a new List with new ids every time it never bothers to try assigning the work to any of them.

Comment: Putting the same instance in the list twice is a bad practice anyway because it skews the entity selection probability. But the planningId functionally indeed detects it and fails-fast on it. I'll improve the error message.

Comment: @Matt different issue, new stackoverflow question please :)

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet There is no duplicate instance in any one call to get the list but it seems to be that optaplanner is combining calls to create duplication.  See edited question for progress.  Not sure I understand what the new question should be, sorry.

Comment: @Matt I think you misunderstood my last comment. If you have **multiple lists** containing problem facts (so multiple `@ProblemFactCollectionProperty` annotations), then these lists should contain unique facts (so not a single fact appears in both lists). If you have just one list, my previous suggestion doesn't apply (it was a long shot). You certainly shouldn't return different instances in the same list, or different id's for the same fact because that will indeed lead to Optaplanner not assigning any entities. It would really help if you showed your solution class, if possible of course :)

Comment: @n1ck Oh, my apologies. Still I think I learnt something from meddling with it anyway.  Hopefully question now includes what you wanted to see.  Thanks for all the input.

Comment: @Matt well, that helped, because I think I have spotted it: you have specified the `@ProblemFactCollectionProperty` above both your fields and getters. This wil result in the 'working objects must be unique' error. I would suggest removing the annotation from the fields (both workerList and travelTimes). Please confirm so I can update the answer

Comment: @n1ck I could kiss you! Update your answer please. :)