# Optaplanner 7.9.0 Multithreading - Solution not reproducable

Tags: optaplanner

Having updated to 7.9.0 and after initial problems: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51597744/optaplanner-7-9-0-and-adding-multithreading-same-planningid-exception I now have been trying to test and compare to my 7.7.0 version.  However I cannot get it to reproduce the same solution everytime (obviously only with the same problem data) as in my older version, even when explicitly set in the config xml.  Is there additional set up for this version required?

**Edit**: Did some testing and found switching to TABU (haven't been through them all) gave me the expected consistency:

Extra Cores:1 - DEFAULT:

```
            Score (Hrd:Med:Sft) Time Taken (Minutes:Seconds)
Test1       0:0:-7609           0:08
Test2       0:-1:-7758          0:13
Test3       0:-1:-7705          0:14
```

Extra Cores:1 - TABU:

```
            Score (Hrd:Med:Sft) Time Taken (Minutes:Seconds)
Test1       0:0:-7763           1:29
Test2       0:0:-7763           1:29
Test3       0:0:-7763           1:28
```

Between two runs of the former the solution diverges at LS step 28:

```
LS step (25), time spent (1869), score (0hard/-3medium/-8155soft),
LS step (26), time spent (1890), score (0hard/-3medium/-8339soft),
LS step (27), time spent (1895), score (0hard/-3medium/-8126soft),
**LS step (28), time spent (1909), score (0hard/-3medium/-8256soft),
LS step (29), time spent (1915), score (0hard/-3medium/-8438soft),
LS step (30), time spent (1924), score (0hard/-3medium/-8620soft),
LS step (31), time spent (1952), score (0hard/-3medium/-8639soft),**
```

...and...

```
LS step (25), time spent (1385), score (0hard/-3medium/-8155soft),
LS step (26), time spent (1407), score (0hard/-3medium/-8339soft),
LS step (27), time spent (1412), score (0hard/-3medium/-8126soft),
**LS step (28), time spent (1422), score (0hard/-3medium/-8217soft),
LS step (29), time spent (1436), score (0hard/-3medium/-8336soft),
LS step (30), time spent (1442), score (0hard/-3medium/-8517soft),
LS step (31), time spent (1448), score (0hard/-3medium/-8571soft),**
```

Don't know if that all makes it more or less likely to be problem/solution set up or something else.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's define reproducible: getting the same result at the same step iteration. If the CPU time is completely the same (which it never is), this also means getting the same result after the same amount of time. So you might need to run it a bit longer to get the same amount of steps.

**Multithreaded solving is reproducible if and only if the same `moveThreadCount` is used.** A run with `<moveThreadCount>4</>` is NOT reproducible by a `<moveThreadCount>2</>`. Even a run with `<moveThreadCount>NONE</>` is not reproducible with a run with `<moveThreadCount>1</>` (the latter being useless except for QA btw).

Look at your score calculation speed.

- If it's lower, you probably forgot to increase the memory size and GC churns are hurting you.
- If that's higher, you'd normally get a better result. If you see a worse result anyway, the config might have been *overfitted* for the no move threads. Use additional datasets in optaplanner-benchmark to prove or disprove that.

Furthermore, if you use `<moveThreadCount>AUTO</>`, it's only reproducible on the same machine, because AUTO changes the moveThreadCount depending on the number of CPU cores in the machine.

Comment: Doesn't need to be the same per step as such, just the same score at the end.  I'm using the same <moveThreadCount>1</> each time (I believe this is one extra cpu core) and without changing anything per run I get a different score each time (and always last changed long before it's time was up.) I've subsequently tried increasing the allowed time to solve but still get a very varied result.  I'll double check the calculation speed but not sure I understand what you mean by 'the config might have been overfitted for the no move threads', my apologies.

Comment: Just found: 'This can be 1 to enforce running the multithreaded code with only 1 move thread (which is less efficient than NONE).', so I guess I can't test the improvement on a 2 core machine anyway. D'oh!

Comment: @Matt Try putting it to 2 on that 2-core machine and let me know if the score calculation speed is better than NONE (but 1 should always be worse than NONE). Theoretically it would be better, because the solver thread won't take a full cpu, so the 2 move threads can utilize more than 1 cpu. But in practice the Operation System and other JVM threads and other processes also take CPU power...

Comment: "without changing anything per run I get a different score each time" Do you also get a different result at the same step (turn on DEBUG logging to see all steps). If you do, that's a bug in our reproducible guarantee and I 'd like a jira+reproducer so we can fix it:)

Comment: Tried setting it to 2 and that seemed to take a bit longer but get better scores however still varied from run to run.  Captured the output from two tests,  one straight after the other and they got to LS step (27) looking identical and thereafter diverged.  However, if I switch to using the TABU algorithm, that DOES give consistent results across multiple runs. (Until I set the moveThreadCount to 2 but I'm guessing that's creating some sort of contention/bottlenecking as the threads fight for a cpu core that doesn't exist???)

Comment: Forgot to say I've edited the question to include more details on this.

Comment: That log clearly proves it's a bug, please create a jira.